# How to initialize a value in web.xml from a JNDI variable?

Tags: java, jndi, web.xml, deployment-descriptor

In my Java web application, the NTLM domain controller name is specified in web.xml like this:

```
<filter>
<!-- other code -->
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jcifs.http.domainController</param-name>
        <param-value>DCNAME</param-value>
   </init-param>
<!-- other code -->
</filter>
```

In the above XML, we've hard-coded the domain controller name (DCNAME) in the param-value tag.

Now, **is it possible to read this 'DCNAME' from a JNDI variable**, instead of hard-coding it in web.xml file?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

See this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html). You need to define an environment resource like this:

```
 <Environment name="myName" value="whatever"
         type="java.lang.String" override="false"/>
```

and then read it from code:

```
Context initCtx = new InitialContext();
Context envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
String myName = (String) envCtx .lookup("myName");
```

Comment: That's very Tomcat specific, the original question does not say anything about Tomcat.

Comment: The link is Tomcat specific, but the code snippet is not.  What is missing is that the code need to be called from within a Servlet listener's contextInitialized event. See this: http://www.coderanch.com/t/362833/Servlets/java/log-ServletContextListener

Answer (score 0):

Can read it inside the init() of the servlet using JNDI to which you are passing this param.